# Remove "comparison is always false" warnings using code tweaks

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, compiler-warnings, clang++

I am working on a huge C++ project, and to have something very clean, all warnings are turned into errors on purpose (flag `-Werror` with g++ or clang++).

I have a template class A:

```
template<int N> class A { ... };
```

Depending on the value of `N`, some general behaviors are varying. In one of `A`'s methods, I have a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) { ... }
```

In this for loop declaration,`M` is calculated from `N` which is resolved at compile time (multiplications of compilation-solved constants).

For some values of `N`, there are cases where the for loop is equivalent to:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 0; i++) { ... }
```

but this was made on purpose, I just want the loop to be removed by the optimizer.

With g++, there is no problem. However, with clang++, I get:

```
error: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-compare]
```

which is obvious and right.

My question is:

Is there some kind of tweak that could discard this warning by making the for loop not being taken into account? I am talking about a tweak implying pure C++ code and no clang-reserved pragmas since my code must work with both g++ and clang++.

I have thought about something like:

```
if(M > 0) for(unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++) { ... }
```

but this just gives the same error. Any idea?

Comment: "flag -Werr with g++ or -Werror with clang++" - No need to make them different `-Werror` works fine with both compilers.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang have pragmas to temporarily disable warnings for a section of code. If no warning is generated, then there will be no error either. As for *which* warning to disable, it's in the error message.

Comment: Unsigned can't be less than zero so the compiler is right to warn you about that. It's an overkill to check if unsigned can be less than `0`.

Comment: Oh and once you temporarily disable the warning, you have to make sure that the compiler actually does what you hope it will do (optimize the loop away). But you should probably try to come up with a way to not execute the loop if `N` is `0` just to be safe anyway.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that produces the warning? I was [unable to reproduce it](https://godbolt.org/g/Y2EJaG)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for the flag info, I'll edit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As I said, I'm not satisfied with pragmas since they potentially throw warnings if not used with the right compiler.

Comment: What about:  for(unsigned int i = 0; (i+1) < (M+1); i++) ?  Not a very optimized solution for sure!

Comment: Would you be able to use `if constexpr (M > 0) ...` (requires C++17)?

Comment: @avariant That's actually a smart one! For the optimization, the compiler would probably detect the +1 both sides of the comparison operator and prune (maybe) so it could in fact be quite optimized.

Comment: @DanielSchepler My code has to be C++11-compliant unfortunately.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois You could still use [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) with tag dispatch, though: `return foo_impl(std::integral_constant<(type of M), M>{});` and have two overloads of `foo_impl`, one for `std::integral_constant<(type of M), 0>`, and one for arbitrary `I`

Comment: Why do you need `unsigned`  int there? Make it signed and the error will go away.

Comment: You already need to have a compiler-specific solution it seems, so why not put the pragmas inside a simple `#ifdef/#endif` block?

Comment: *"For the optimization, the compiler would probably detect the +1 both sides"*: I cannot remove it for `unsigned` as `max_value + 1` would be `0` and change the test. (It would be allowed for `signed` thanks to UB of that case).

Answer (score 0):

A solution I thought about while writing this post would be to replace `unsigned int` by `int` and use `static_cast<unsigned int>(i)` inside the for loop if needed. But it took me too long to write just to delete it.
Anyway, any more elegant solution would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In c++17, you may use `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr (M > 0) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++) { ... }
}
```

Before you might use specialization

```
template <std::size_t M>
void bar(/*...*/) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++) { ... }
}

template <>
void bar<0>(/*...*/) {
    /* Empty */
}
```